# What tables structure is better?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema, ddl

I'm developing a multiuser task manager application but I've stumbled upon database schema design. I have user table, category and of course task table. Each task belongs to exactly one category. So in DDL words I need a "one-to-many" relation between category and task, right? Also I'm almost sure I need "one-to-many" relation between user and task entities. (Please, correct me if I'm wrong). As for the "category - user" relation, here I'm seriously considering two options and I need you to tell me which one is correct and why:

1. The "many-to-many" relation i.e. user can have many categories and vise-versa;
2. The "one-to-many" relation where each category can relate to only one user. In this case in category table is going to be plenty of rows with similar names such as "work","family" etc. (since it's hard to come up with something new and original when it comes to categories) which will differ only by "user" column value.

What approach is common in this situation?

Comment: Why do you need a table for `category - user`? You can get this by joining the relation tables for `task_category` and `user_task`.

Comment: Actually you may be right. I try and can't think of any cons of this solution. Do you really think I would benefit by doing it your way?

Comment: I can't see a need to link users with categories either, unless you want each user to "own" or "create" their own categories for some reason. If user 1 and user 2 both want a category called "work", it should really be a shared category unless there is a specific reason for it not to be (for example, if there are other attributes on category that should be user-specific). In that case, category would have a foreign key to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tricky question, as both approaches have advantages. You probably need to better define your problem and what you want to accomplish.

I'm working on a similar project, with a structure like this:

- An user table, basic info
- A self related task table, allowing to create 'projects' (a task with no parent) and depending tasks (*"this task shouldn't start until previous task is completed"*)
- A many-to-many allocation table, connecting multiple users to multiple tasks (*"this work must be done by user1 and user2 working together"*)

And here your question come back: how users are suppose to organize their pending tasks?

- If your project is more like a to-do list, you don't need that allocation table; stick with your *"Each task belongs to exactly one category"* statement
- If users should be allowed to create their own categories, you probably need to create a `user-categories` table, with category information and a foreign key to user table
- If users must pick a previously created category from a common list, you don't need that user FK
- Anyway, if users could to categorize their allocated tasks, this category table will be a foreign key in the allocation table, so every user could to categorize their own tasks

In my experience, you should to delay this category decision and ask your users; they will point you in the right direction.

You can also simply create that `user-catogories` table, as it's more flexible than the alternative and ignore that data repetition. Using a basic categories list with many-to-many relationship with users probably will be a bad idea, since a user could decide to rename a category and all other users will be affected by this action.

Comment: I want to allow each user create his own categories and manage them as he/she desires including renaming it and deleting. What solution should I pick in that case? I can't grasp your point from you post sorry

Comment: Create `user-categories` table (id, name, FK to user), and add a FK to this table from your task table.